# MongoDb multiply aggregate returns null sometimes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this aggregate:

```
const dpi = (imgSize.height * imgSize.width) / (printDpi * printDpi);
    let printSizes = await printSizeModel
      .aggregate([
        {
          $project: {
            id: 1,
            width: 1,
            height: 1,
            price: 1,
            shippingWidth: 1,
            shippingHeight: 1,
            shippingLength: 1,
            shippingWeight: 1,
            framePrice: 1,
            hasFrame: 1,
            total: { $multiply: ['$width', '$height'] },
          },
        },
        { $match: { total: { $lt: dpi } } },
      ])
      .exec();
```

Width and height are both numbers and DPi is number as well (DPI is float and width and height are int)

I am using mongoos and Nodejs. This aggregate sometimes returns correct result and sometimes returns null. Based on my understanding this should be correct, but I might be missing something in here

Comment: Please provide input (dpi) & sample docs !! Also if it's working intermittently do you've request where it's not working ?

Comment: One of them that I tested and returned nothing was :476.91609977324265

Comment: not sure why, but you might be missing something, if total is always a number, passing dpi as `476.91609977324265` should work.

Comment: Total is always a number. One of my wild guesses is that because the 476..... is float with many digits, it confuses the DB and it does not return anything. I converted it to int and I am observing if that solves the problem. But if you have any other suggestions that can help I would appreciate it.

Comment: Ohh yeah that could the issue :-)

Answer (score 0):

After using Math.ceil to convert the number to Int the issue went away, so I can say that the issue was the float number:

```
const dpi = Math.ceil((imgSize.height * imgSize.width) / (printDpi * printDpi));
    let printSizes = await printSizeModel
      .aggregate([
        {
          $project: {
            id: 1,
            width: 1,
            height: 1,
            price: 1,
            shippingWidth: 1,
            shippingHeight: 1,
            shippingLength: 1,
            shippingWeight: 1,
            framePrice: 1,
            hasFrame: 1,
            total: { $multiply: ['$width', '$height'] },
          },
        },
        { $match: { total: { $lt: dpi } } },
      ])
      .exec();
```